# Writing sum of squares functionally in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

So I have these 4 examples, 3 of which I got from this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ887aOZITY).

I just took a class on functional programming (in Racket) and I was if my basic understanding of F# is right.

```
let data = [1.;2.;3.;4.]

let sqr x = x * x

// Bad, very bad   
let sumOfSquareI nums =
    let mutable acc = 0.0
    for x in nums do
        acc <- acc + sqr x
    acc

// Better than above, but may cause stack overflow with very long list    
let rec sumOfSquareF1 nums = 
    match nums with 
    | [] -> 0.0
    | h::t -> sqr h + sumOfSquareF1 t

// much much better, uses tail-recursion, no stack overflow  
let sumOfSquareF2 nums =
    let rec sumOfSquareLocal nums acc = 
        match nums with
        | [] -> acc
        | h::t -> sumOfSquareLocal t (acc + sqr h)
    sumOfSquareLocal nums 0.0

// seems to be idiomatic F#, but is it better than tail-recursive version?    
let sumOfSquare nums =
    nums
    |> Seq.map sqr
    |> Seq.sum    

sumOfSquare data
sumOfSquareI data
sumOfSquareF1 data
sumOfSquareF2 data
```

Is there any real difference between the last two functions? Is one better than the other? When writing functional code in F# just how often should I be using the |> operator (which is completely new to me)?

Another thing is there a different way to create a list in F#? What I pulled from the video seems ...clunky.

Comment: `Is there any real difference between the last two functions?` Use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or [IL Disassembler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) to look at the IL code.

Comment: `Is one better than the other` That is a subjective question.

Comment: `When writing functional code in F# just how often should I be using the |> operator` Think Unix pipes. It also helps for type inferencing.

Comment: Of interest: [F# Cheat sheet](https://dungpa.github.io/fsharp-cheatsheet/)

Comment: I think the word you should use instead of `better` for this question is `idiomatic`. At SO subjective questions are frowned upon at best an typically closed. For the F# tag, questions about `idiomatic` seem to be popular and get many answers.

Comment: Since you appear to be new to F#, check out the [F# tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/info) especially the site [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) and the videos there. There is enough info in those two links to keep you learning for weeks if not months and don't be afraid to ask here. The worse that happens is that we vote to close your question.

Comment: Also check out the [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) where you can compare [F#](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:F_Sharp) and [Racket](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Racket) code

Comment: Your "tail-recursive" example is not in fact tail-recursive as is - you meant it to say `sumOfSquareLocal t (acc + sqr h)`.

Comment: Your question solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you should prefer using the higher-order functions in the `Seq` and `List` modules over explicit recursion. You can also use `sumBy`:

```
let sumOfSquare nums = nums |> Seq.sumBy sqr
```

Answer (score 5):

Discussions about programming styles or paradigms easily turn into opinion-based reasoning. Let's have a look at what really matters in real-world implications for each of the functions.

**Version 1: imperative**

This one costs five trivial lines. Pretty much everyone can read it. The "state machine" is a single variable and easy to verify. It's not generic, but `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` instead of `0.0` could fix that, albeit at the cost of some length.

I wouldn't call this "bad, very bad" when compared with the others. Unless you make programming a cult where the imperative deviants must be destroyed by the divine functional truth. It's not minimal either though.

**Version 2: recursive calculation**

It's fairly readable, uses a line less. Again, not generic, but generic zero could fix that. *However*, this function will cause the stack to grow! Someone using it will see it working fine in first tests, until suddenly, performance plummets or the whole program crashes!

*I think this is objectively the worst of the presented solutions! You do NOT want to have this in production code!*

**Version 3: nested tail-recursive function**

Again, this can be made generic. This one works well and is functional, but it's 6 lines, and I'd not call three of them trivial anymore.

*This is pure, but honestly, if I had to choose between this and the imperative variant, I'd not be very sure.*

**Version 4: call higher-order function**

Short and readable, and generic without use of weird primitives! Why would you doubt this is the winner of the four?

**Extra version: none at all**

Higher-order functions work so well for this, this isn't the end. `Seq.sumBy sqr` (which I see Lee beat me to in his answer) does the job. Since this is barely longer than `sumOfSquares`, in production code, there might not be a reason to define an extra function at all.

**Readability is key**

When you ask for advice on when to use pipeline operators and the likes, the answer has to optimize for the people who will read the code. The compiler surely doesn't care how many parentheses you throw about. Think about who will read the code, and optimize for that.

When writing code mostly for yourself, go with whatever combination takes you the least time to navigate and interpret. Pipelines are awesome to avoid gotchas like lots of closing parentheses that are really hard to keep count of.

PS: there are lots of ways to initialize [lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx). In this case, `[1. .. 4.]` would do the job.

Comment: The OP used a `mutable` for example one. In my book if mutable can be avoided but is used makes it `bad,very bad`

Comment: For `[1. .. 4.] ` I like to add the zero so that you don't gloss over it and think it is an int. e.g. `[1.0 .. 4.0] `

Comment: @GuyCoder Granted, in this case there's no need for any complexity. But why would the mutating version be worse than the confusing nested function? From what I know, the main problems with mutability come from the difficulty to manage complicated state spaces, with subtle order-dependence and the likes eating the programmer's attention. But if there's only one variable, which serves one purpose, and its state progression is trivial, for whom is that very bad? I have no doubt about the costs of *complex* state, but why worry about cases like this?

Comment: The reasons I seek to avoid mutability are 1. When you go to write code that is provable, having a mutable makes it much harder to prove. 2. Writing [Async](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Async_Workflows#Problems_with_Mutable_State) code. I am NOT against mutables when needed; as a matter of fact I am writing a disassembler that can also unit test the assembly an in that I have to use mutables and a whole bunch of code that I would not recommend in general for F#, but because it has to rely on low level Windows functions, that is the price that must be paid.

Comment: Additionally for me personally, the more I write code without mutables, the more I write better functional code. I often tend to think in terms of mathematical expressions when writing functional code and as you note, the mutables make reasoning about it much harder. So the more I can avoid using mutables even when learning, the more likely I am able to solve a problem functionally without them. In this case I think it is bad advise to open the door for the OP; my advise to the OP is to avoid mutables if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The most important difference between your functions is how generic they are. Let's take a look at their types:

```
val sumOfSquareI : nums:seq<float> -> float
val sumOfSquareF1 : nums:float list -> float
val sumOfSquareF2 : nums:float list -> float
val sumOfSquare : nums:seq<float> -> float
```

As you can see, `sumOfSquare` and `sumOfSquareI` are more generic then the others - they work with any sequences, not only lists.

As far as difference in style of `sumOfSquare` and `sumOfSquareF2` is concerned, I personally like `sumOfSquare` much better. Thanks to the pipe operator and lack of recursion you can simply read code from top to bottom and at every line you know exactly what's happening.

As Lee pointed pointed out, you can use a built-in `Seq.sumBy` function:

```
let sumOfSquareBiref nums = nums |> Seq.sumBy sqr
```

If you make a call to this function later in a file (so that input parameter can be inferred), you can even skip the argument and write:

```
let sumOfSquareBirefer = Seq.sumBy sqr
```

At that point you have to ask yourself if you want to define a separate function or simply inline `(Seq.sumBy sqr input)` in your code. You should consider whether the function is likely to change and how many times it is used in your source.

Comment: Did you mean `sumOfSquareF2` and `sumOfSquare`?

Comment: @DaBest when I talked about style - yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lee pointed out, higher-order functions are usually preferred over explicit recursion in F#.

Just to add another solution to yours, for number algorithms in F#, it is usually more idiomatic to mark the function as `inline`, such as

```
let inline sumOfSquares s = Seq.sumBy (fun x -> pown x 2) s
```

So that its signature becomes:

```
val sumOfSquares : s:seq<'a> -> 'a (requires member get_Zero and member (+) and member get_One and member (*) and member (/))
```

which means you can call it on any primitive number types:

```
sumOfSquares <| seq { for x in 1..5 -> x } // seq<int>
sumOfSqaures <| seq { for x in 1. .. 5. -> x } // seq<float>
sumOfSqaures [1..5] // int list
sumOfSquares [1. .. 5.] // float list
```

which is more generic and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a list with a list comprehension or just simply with `[1..10]`

Comment: His list is floats. Did you mean: `[1.0 .. 4.0]`

Comment: I meant generally, even  `['a'..'z']` but yes using floats explicitly is correct for this Q. Or `[for in in 1.0 ..4.0 -> i * i]`.

Comment: `[for i in  1.0 ..4.0 -> i * i]`

Comment: It is just not your day. :) Did you mean `in` instead of `in in`?